# Best way to save random questions and answers in a MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create a sort of poll with random questions and I wanted to ask you whether the best way to store these random questions in my MySQL db would be

- storing the questions as string, which means I would extract via PHP the random questions from the bunch I've got and save them in the database like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/1fb3e9e660ffd2e662b2359b427358c6.png)
- storing the questions' IDs as a string (e.g. "1_2_3_4_5") and then using PHP I get an array out of it using explode() and take out of the array with the questions' texts using the IDs:
  [Table](https://i.gyazo.com/01ff6c03679b3139e4bde9bee50930e1.png).
- or please suggest me a better method.

Thank you really much, appreciate your support, I hope I explained it clearly and sorry for mistakes.

Comment: _I wanted to ask you_ and _the best way_. _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._ This seems off topic, but I don't know, maybe someone gives you a hint. Please, take a look at [Help Center > Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: @FirstOne I don't actually think so, because what I'm aiming for is to get suggestions to improve/to develop my application the best way in the sense of optimisation.

Comment: Whether Too Broad or Primarily Opinion based, this is not a great question for SO.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a table for Questions and a table for QuestionResponses, at a minimum. QuestionResponses can have a foreign key reference to Questions, along with a VARCHAR(SOMELENGTH) field for storing the response.

Comment: Like this? https://gyazo.com/51ed5f3326968f7cf8262316e7f763b7

Comment: That works! Depending on what you are ultimately attempting to accomplish you may or may not want to store some additional information and abstract your data relationships a step further.

Comment: For example, you may want to add a column for Username on QuestionResponses table so you can later map question responses to users. Better yet, you could create a Users table, and then add a column to the QuestionResponses table for userId (as a foreign key reference to the Users table ID column). This style of database structure is highly normalized and will provide optimal modularity moving forward if you plan on adding additional features to your code later.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your first option. You can just store the questions as strings in the database, and use php/pdo to randomly select the amount of questions you want per time in an array, then print out the array content randomly. (English is hard sometimes, so i'll explain again)...

Say you want to produce 5 random questions per user that tries to use the application, you can have at least 50 questions in the database stored as string, then "randomly" select 10 questions from the database (this is to avoid selecting all the questions every time or selecting the same set of questions), from the 10 randomly selected questions (which is now in an array), you can randomly print out 5 for the user.

So you have two sets of randomization.

I hope this makes a little sense and helpful too.

I can explain myself better if you have any more questions.

Thank you.